# Using System.threading, how to check and terminate an already started iTask in case of running for an specific amount of time

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe, indy, idhttp

I'm a novice in `Multithreading`, i have a procedure that goes through a series of operations using indy (login to a site and download files and ...), sometimes when a site is not responsive or it takes too long, no exception occurs even with `idHttp.connectTimeout` and `idHttp.readTimeout` set to a specific amount or sometimes it does occur but not at the time i have specified !!, which is why i prefer to check the task and see if for example an `ITask` is running for 30 sec, it must be terminated !, i tried using `itask.cancel` but it only cancels if something is in queue and doesn't terminate a task that is already running, what is the solution to my problem ?

**just so you know what is happening in my program  :**

originally my program creates classes based on a list of profiles and starts a process of login and download, i want to terminate any `startDownloadProcess` that takes more than 30 sec
**here is a code example  :**

```
// this is what i used to do
for I := 0 to mProfileList.count - 1 do
begin
  myClass := TMyClass.create(mProfileList[i]);
  //sometimes this takes a very very long time and i don't want that.
  myClass.startDownloadProcess;
end;

// here is what i have in mind 
for I := 0 to mProfileList.count - 1 do
begin
  mITaskArray[i] := TTask.run(procedure
    begin
     myClass := TMyClass.create(mProfileList[i]);
     myClass.startDownloadProcess;
    end);
end;
```

**What i need :**
i want each task to depend on the previous one (a queue) and wait until the previous one completes, and if a task takes more than 30 second, it terminates and the queue continues.

now i know there might be a lot of things wrong with that code but that is why i'm here, i'm a bit lost about how to proceed or if what i'm doing is correct at all !

Comment: You must regularly check inside the task if it is being cancelled: `if TTask.CurrentTask.Status = TTaskStatus.Canceled then exit;`

Comment: @LURD but doesn't the task run only one time ?, if so how can i check for status if it gets stuck at a line (for example IdHttp.get());

Comment: You can't terminate tasks and threads from the outside. You need them to cooperate. You can terminate processes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan considering my problem and what i need to do, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Exactly what has already been suggesyed

Comment: Ali, `IdHttp` does its work in a thread of its own. A safe way to stop that work is to define an `OnWork` handler and call `Disconnect` inside that handler if time is out.

Comment: @LURD `TTask`, not `TIdHTTP`, runs in its own thread. `TIdHTTP` does its work in whatever thread is calling `Get`/`Post`. But it doesn't matter, since the `OnWork` events are fired only when bytes are actively being exchanged, so if the site is not responding then there is no socket activity to fire the events. You have to use socket timeouts. Definitely use `ConnectTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` (there is no `SendTimeout` in Indy, but the underlying socket has its own `SO_SNDTIMEO` option at the API level), and also consider enabling TCP keepalives as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau finally remy, i was waiting for u!, what do you think about an stopwatch that starts at onWorkBegin and resets at onWork, and in another thread it checks and if the stopwatch time passes the threshold, i cause an error so an exception occurs at idhttp, do you think something like this can work ?

Comment: @AliAhmadi: The only way to "cause an error so an exception occurs" would be to close the `TIdHTTP` socket directly.  But even then, that is not guaranteed to work on all platforms. Before resorting to that, I would suggesting trying with socket-level timeouts+keepalives first.

Answer (score 1):

you say you are new in multithreading, so remember to never (never) use the TTASK/ITask or similar TParalel. it's completely buggy ! use instead TAnonymousThread

```
  MyThread := TThread.createAnonymousThread(
    Procedure
    Begin
       repeat
         if MyThread.checkterminated then exit;
         if moreThan30secondsRunning then exit;
         ....
       until wordDone;
    end).start;
```